# MySQL PHP Insert into Two Tables Transaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

I'm trying to insert into two different tables and it works without the foreach statements but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong once I add the foreach... Here is the SQL/PHP query:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($GLOBALS['db_host'],$GLOBALS['db_name'],$GLOBALS['db_password'],$GLOBALS['db_user']);


if (!$con) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}   
mysqli_autocommit($con, FALSE);

$i = 0;
$end = count($_POST['category_id']);    
$end2 = count($_POST['benefit_id']);


$sql="INSERT INTO store_locator_category_map (id,category_id)
VALUES ";
foreach ($_POST['category_id'] as $category_id) {
        if(++$i === $end) { 
        $sql .="('".$id."', '".$category_id."');";
        } else  $sql .="('".$id."', '".$category_id."'), ";
    }           
mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$sql2="INSERT INTO store_locator_benefit_map (id,benefit_id)
VALUES ";
foreach ($_POST['benefit_id'] as $benefit_id) {
        if(++$i === $end2) { 
        $sql2 .="('".$id."', '".$benefit_id."');";
        } else  $sql2 .="('".$id."', '".$benefit_id."'), ";
    }

mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

if (!mysqli_commit($con)) {
    print("Transaction commit failed\n");
    exit();
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what the `$_POST['category_id']` and `$_POST['benefit_id']` values are, it is difficult to answer.  However, assuming those two variables are not coming in as enumerable types (e.g. array), that would be instant cause for investigation.

For example, suppose your `$_POST['category_id']` was the string "Some sample string", as shown below:

```
ubuntu@linuxbox:~$ cat test.php
<?php
$x = "Some sample string";
foreach($x as $y) {
        echo $y;
}
ubuntu@linuxbox:~$ php test.php
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ubuntu/test.php on line 3
```

In the scenario where you run a `foreach` operation against a string, it flat-out fails.  Another possible explanation (perhaps addressed outside of the code sample) is that `$id` isn't being assigned within this code sample.

Also, as a point of concern, I would caution against taking a `$_POST` value and generating your SQL from that using concatenation, as you are exposing yourself to SQL injection attacks.  Consider some means of sanitizing your inputs before using concatenation, unless you explicitly trust the source of the request.

Comment: Oops, to clarify, the $_POST is coming from a checkbox list and the $id is assigned. I'll take a look again. Thanks for your quick response!